# MS Access INSERT not using the input

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

I am trying to add records to my Microsoft access database through my web form. but every time i fill in the fields (name, email etc) and click submit all i get in the database is the VALUES from the query i.e. @Name @Email.

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO [tblEnquiry]([Name], [Email], [Contact_Number], [Enquiry]) 
VALUES ('@Name', '@Email', '@Contact_Number', '@Enquiry')
```

I would like it to populate the database with the data the user inputs rather than everytime the user fills in the form a record like this appears in the database:

```
ID  Name    Email   Contact_Number  Enquiry
2   Name    Email   Contact_Number  Enquiry
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using quotes, which turns those variables into strings, preventing the DB from seeing them AS variables. Try

```
INSERT .... VALUES(@Name, @Email, etc...)
```

instead. Note the lack of quotes around the `@foo` variables.